# Prove that every $G$-invariant subspace of $V \otimes U$ has the form $V \otimes U_{0}$.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, invariant-theory

Knowing the following theorem:

> **Theorem 4.** Let $T$ be an irreducible complex representation of the group $G$ in the space $V$, and let $I$ be the trivial representation of $G$ in the space $U$. Then every minimal subspace $W \subset V \otimes U$ invariant under the representation $TI$ has the form $V \otimes u_0$, where $u_0 \in U$.

[image]

How can I prove that:

> Every $G$-invariant subspace of $V \otimes U$ has the form  $V \otimes U_{0}$, where $U_{0}$ is a  subspace of $U$.

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: A $G$-invariant subspace is a sum of minimal $G$-invariant subspaces.

Comment: What is the relation between your hint and the theorem mentioned above Max, the question says under the assumptions of theorem 4 prove that ..... Could you please clarify more ?

Comment: @Max this question from the book of Vinberg section 4

Comment: It is related in that you already know what minimal invariant subspaces look like, and I just told you how to relate any invariant subspace to minimal ones

Comment: @Max my professor said that your first comment is generally incorrect ..... it is correct iff $G$ is finite dimensional ...... so why $G$ is finite dimensional in our case?

Comment: $G$ is not finite dimensional, it's finite, or the space is finite dimensional, don't mix the two. I agree that it need not be true if $G$ is infinite (though that's not an iff). I was assuming that $G$ was finite in my comment. If it's not it might require a bit more work, but then again so must the theorem. I'll write an answer when I have the time

Comment: Thank you so much ...... I appreciate this @Max

Comment: Actually I realized the proof I had in mind still used that either $V$ is finite dimensional (no assumptions on $U$ or $G$ though). I'll think about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works whenever $V$ has dimension $< |\mathbb{C}|=\mathfrak{c}$, so it is not a complete answer.

I will use the Jacobson density theorem, as stated for instance on [the wikipedia page with the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_density_theorem#Motivation_and_formal_statement) (I will use left modules instead of right modules but that doesn't matter of course):

> **The Jacobson Density Theorem.** Let $U$ be a simple left $R$-module, $D = \operatorname{End}\left(_R U\right)$, and $X \subset U$ a finite and $D$-linearly independent set. If $A$ is a $D$-linear transformation on $U$ then there exists $r \in R$ such that $A\left(x\right) = rx$ for all $x \in X$. (Isaacs, Theorem 13.14, p. 185.)

Indeed $V$ is an irreducible representation of $G$, hence a simple $\mathbb{C}G$-module.

Now by Schur's lemma, with our hypothesis on the dimension of $V$, $End_{\mathbb{C}G}(V) = \mathbb{C}Id$ (the usual form of Schur's lemma assumes finite dimensions, but actually you can make it work if the dimension is strictly smaller than the size of the field - if you don't know about that I can add a few words for that).

Therefore, using the notations of wikipedia, that is $D=End_{\mathbb{C}G}(V) = \mathbb{C}Id$, a subset $X$ of $V$ is $D$-linearly independent if and only if it is $\mathbb{C}$-linearly independent, and a $D$-linear map is simply a linear map: we will use this.

Let $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ be a basis for $V$.

Let's now get to the proof : let $W\subset V\otimes U$ be a $G$-invariant subspace, and let $\displaystyle\sum_{i\in J}e_i\otimes u_i\in W$, with $J$ a finite subset of $I$, $u_i\in U\setminus\{0\}$ for $i\in J$.

Then for all $\alpha\in \mathbb{C}G$ as $W$ is $G$-invariant and $U$ has a trivial $G$-action, we get that $\displaystyle\sum_{i\in J}(\alpha e_i)\otimes u_i \in W$.

Let $i\in J$ and $j \in I$, and let $f_{ij}:V\to V$ be defined by sending every $e_k$ to $0$ except for $e_i$, which it sends to $e_j$. Then $f_{ij}$ is linear, hence $D$ linear. Hence, by the Jacobson density theorem, since $X=\{e_j, j\in J\}$ is linearly independent, hence $D$-linearly independent, we get that there is $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}G$ such that $f_{ij}(x)= \alpha x$ for $x\in X$. In particular $e_j\otimes u_i =\displaystyle\sum_{k\in J}\alpha e_k\otimes u_k\in W$.

Therefore $V\otimes u_i\subset W$ for all $i$. So now if you take $U_0 = \{u\in U\mid \exists i\in I, e_i\otimes u \in W\}$.

By the Jacobson density theorem again, it follows that $U_0$ is a subspace of $U$, moreover by the above proof it's clear that $V\otimes U_0 = W$.

I don't know if the result is true when $V$ has arbitrary dimension, and if it is I don't know how to prove it (yet). I do suspect that the result you were expected to prove had some kind of finiteness assumptions. If you have some finiteness assumptions ($G$ finite, or more generally $V$ finite dimensional), the proof becomes much easier

Comment: I am not sure about your definition of $U_0$, but there is an easier way to complete your proof: For each $i \in I$, let $f_i : V \otimes U \to U$ be the map sending each $e_k \otimes u$ to $0$ if $k \neq i$ and to $u$ if $k = i$. (This is an example of tensor contraction.) Now, set $U_0 = \sum_{i \in I} f_i\left(W\right)$. The argument made earlier proves that $e_k \otimes f_i\left(u\right) \in W$ for each $k \in I$ and $i \in I$; thus, $e_k \otimes U_0 \subset W$ for each $k \in I$; thus, $V \otimes U_0 \subset W$. And of course, the opposite inclusion holds.

Comment: @darijgrinberg : I don't know if it's easier, but of course what's easier depends on people. About my definition of $U_0$ : what I proved earlier was that if $\sum_i e_i\otimes u_i \in W$, then for all $j,i$, $e_j\otimes u_i \in W$, therefore $U_0$ is a good candidate for being a "tensor complement". That it is a subspace is clear because if $e_i\otimes u, e_j \otimes v \in W$, then by the result I just stated, $e_i\otimes v\in W$ as well, so we can just sum them.